# Erro ao executar aplicação ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Estou começando a jornada para aprender ASP.NET Core e quando tento executar a aplicação tenho o seguinte erro:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>   SocketException: Nenhuma conexão pôde ser feita porque a máquina de
>   destino as recusou ativamente
>   System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(string host, int port,
>   CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>
> HttpRequestException: Nenhuma conexão pôde ser feita porque a máquina
>   de destino as recusou ativamente
>   System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(string host, int port,
>   CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>
> HttpRequestException: Failed to proxy the request to
>   http://localhost:4200/, because the request to the proxy target
>   failed. Check that the proxy target server is running and accepting
>   requests to http://localhost:4200/.
>
> The underlying exception message was 'Nenhuma conexão pôde ser feita
>   porque a máquina de destino as recusou ativamente'.Check the
>   InnerException for more details.
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions.Proxy.SpaProxy.PerformProxyRequest(HttpContext
>   context, HttpClient httpClient, Task baseUriTask,
>   CancellationToken applicationStoppingToken, bool proxy404s)

Pensei que talvez pudesse ser algum problema com CORS, porém tanto cliente como servidor estão juntos, então não deve ser esse o problema.

Comment: Esse erro pode ser causado se algum serviço estiver usando a mesma porta

Comment: Creio que não, usei NESTAT pra ver e não tem ninguém usando essa porta. O ISS gera duas opções de porta e o problema acontece nas duas.

Comment: Use p `nestat -anb` depois de iniciar o IIS para ver se está rodando e com a porta esperada. Isso pode ser porta errada, pode ser um firewall bloqueando a conexão, pode ser que não esteja realmente ativo...

Comment: Tem uma VM (vmware) rodando nessa porta, com o comando nestat -anb apareceu. Infelizmente não posso parar e nem mudar a porta desse serviço. É possível mudar a porta da aplicação?

Comment: uma pergunta boba... você está tentando acessar a aplicação partindo da mesma máquina em que ela está rodando, certo?

Answer (score -1):

Comigo aconteceu a mesma coisa, passa rodar eu fiz da seguinte forma, separe os projeto e rodei cada uma em uma janela do Visual Studio 2019 diferente e funcionou pois cada um utiliza uma porta diferente. Eu não consegui achar outra forma melhor, e quando os dois projetos estavam na mesma Soluction eu não consegui configurar o IIS Express para rodar cada um em uma porta diferente.